# Whats best practice? - PHP loop that calls MySQL Stored functions is affecting server performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, for-loop, stored-functions

I have a PHP script that loops through an array and calls a MySQL stored function with each pass.

It is seriously affecting server performance. I think it's bad design on my part. This is how it works (pseudo-code)

1. Gets data from some source in PHP
2. For each item in array

   1. Call MySQL Stored function that inserts/updates data in table
   2. Move to next item
3. End loop

**MySQL Stored Function**

1. searches for a descriptive string(indexed)
2. If it exists assigns whatever ID is associated with it to local variable, else inserts a new one and assigns that new ID to local variable
3. Does similar step above for another string,ID pair
4. Inserts/updates the bulk of the data passed to it

**Attempts at solving it**

- Initially I had 3 separate stored functions, that I then merged to
  one. But it did not solve the issue.
- I also made sure searched fields are indexed
- I have concluded that it is most likely looping through and calling
  the stored functions with each call. That perhaps it assigns a
  process/thread that is not released or is released slowly with each subsequent 
  iteration
- I have read on cursors and I understand they're not good practice
  especially for bulk operations and that there is almost always an
  alternative and more efficient non-procedural(set-based) alternative. Or should I try that route?
- I am yet to try building the entire query text in the loop then running it as one
  big SQL batch. Though I fear time-out issues or more difficulty to track
  insertion/update errors.

Please share your advice and experiences. Pseudocode or snippets would also be appreciated
Thanks in advance!

Comment: SQL works best in set-based operations. Having the PHP code loop and call this function inherently hurts the pipeline. On the other hand, something as simple as *disabling auto-commits* may be sufficient to greatly improve the real-world performance.

Comment: It would be next to impossible to get you useful information without understanding the schema, seeing the actual stored procedure code, and understanding the data to be inserted/updated. You might narrow down this problem by first showing the stored procedure infromation to determine if there is some inherent performance problem there.  You can then work on extrapolating the optimal approach there into a bulk solution.

Comment: If a new connection is being made with each call to mySql maybe you'd benefit from using a persistent connection instead.  That would cut out the time it takes to create each connection and then close each connection.

Comment: Just an idea but maybe have the stored procedure loop through the data instead of PHP?

Comment: @m.e.conroy The connection is persistent. I am yet to try cursors though I understand they are frowned upon for intensive operations

Answer (score 2):

It is always good to reduce the number of queries. In its most basic form, you can insert multiple rows at once.

```
// BAD:
while($something) {
    mysql_query("insert into `table` (`fields`) values ('value')");
}
// GOOD:
$rows = [];
while($something) {
    $rows[] = "('value')";
}
if( $rows) mysql_query("insert into `table` (`fields`) values ".implode(",",$rows));
```

This gets a bit trickier with updates, but it still works:

```
// BAD:
while($something) {
    mysql_query("update `table` set `field`='value' where `id`=".$i);
}
// GOOD:
$rows = [];
while($something) {
    $rows[] = "(".$i.",'value')";
}
if( $rows) mysql_query("insert into `table` (`id`,`fields`) values
          ".implode(",",$rows)." on duplicate key update `fields`=values(`fields`)");
                              // ^ this is where the magic happens.
```

See if you can apply this kind of structure to your queries, and you should see load times go way down for a faster experience!

Comment: The `on duplicate key update` clause is a big code and time saver, and reduces having to query to check if a particular item exists before querying to update or insert it.

Comment: Thanks @Niet the Dark Absol Very helpful insight. I had also considered implode but got stuck on the dependency part where an ID is needed for a subsequent insert/update.(Step 2 in the MySQL function description). How do I manage that? Noting that with each loop a new or old value may be encounterd.But an ID is definitely needed for the final insertion(Step 4 in the MySQL function description)